# nodejs app shuts down on an error

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am running a nodejs app on local machine and I got these 
errors in error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.2.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~prestart: visualapp@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: visualapp@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/martiner/www/visualizationApp/NODEJS/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/martiner/.local/bin:/home/martiner/.local/bin
10 verbose lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/martiner/www/visualizationApp/NODEJS
11 silly lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'nodejs hello.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle visualapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: visualapp@1.0.0 start: `nodejs hello.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid visualapp@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/martiner/www/visualizationApp/NODEJS
17 error Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v4.2.6
20 error npm  v3.5.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error visualapp@1.0.0 start: `nodejs hello.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the visualapp@1.0.0 start script 'nodejs hello.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the visualapp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     nodejs hello.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs visualapp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls visualapp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and I got the following error in the console:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:544:26)
```

I have gone through the code several times and can't figure out where the problem is coming from. 
Could somebody help me to solve this?

### update:

I have a couple of `fs.readFile` and twice using nodemailer. Here is a snippet of it:

```
function sendingMail(p1, user_email, p2, p3, err){

    var first_line_here, number_lines_count;
    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + '/textfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        first_line_here = data.split('\n').shift();
        var number_lines_count = first_line_here.substr(first_line_here.indexOf(":") + 1);

        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
            host: config.smtp,
            secureConnection: false,
            port: config.smtpPort,
            auth: {
              user: config.smtpU,
              pass: config.smtpP
            }
        });
        var mailMessage = '<p>content'</p>';
        var mailOptions = {
            from: config.from,
            to: user_email,
            subject: "Subject Line",
            html: mailMessage
        }
        if (err){
        }

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
          if(error){
              console.log(error);
          }else{
              console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: show us your code...

Comment: @HolgerWill code is 700 lines, is it practical to post it here?

Comment: create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how are you calling sendingMail? make sure the function gets called sequentially.

Comment: @jacky `ECONNRESET` means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the server logs to see if it complains about something.


What could `also` be the case is that at random times, the other side is overloaded and simply kills the connection as a result.

Comment: @jacky `ELIFECYCLE` basically says it fails to spawn your process not due to permission but to an error in your script. Note that it's also telling you to get the latest version of `node` and `npm`.